# Rails: alert user on error from a different server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, web-applications, command-line-interface

I've got two applications: `Interface` is a Rails app and `Processor` is for bash scripts.

I need to notify an `Interface` user's session if a bash process on `Processor` fails. I have access to the command line on `Processor`, so I can hit `http://interface.com/process/12/error/:error_message` with `:error_message` set on `Processor`.

I'm not sure how to make that work though. That route works from the browser, but I don't know how to redirect the user with the error message.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this, I am going to make some assumptions about your setup.  Please correct me if I don't have it right.

I assume that your **Interface** user is monitoring your site by visiting a page such as `http://interface.com/process/12/monitor` on the **Interface** server and you want the error message to pop up to let them know something went wrong.

Given that, consider having your call to `http://interface.com/process/12/error/:error_message` store the error in a related **ProcessError** table.  Then, use javascript on the *monitor* page to poll the **Interface** server for "new" errors.  The polling interval really depends on the situation.  If you're the only user, every second would be fine, but if there are going to be lots of monitoring users at once, you would probably want to make the polling interval longer.  How long depends on load and how important it is that the user is notified quickly.

A *push* solution would be more efficient, but is a bit harder to accomplish.  If this is appealing to you, have a look at [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com), a publish-subscribe messaging system that supports Rails servers and html+javascript clients.

Hopefully this points you in the right direction!

Comment: That's really helpful, thanks! I didn't quite know about the monitoring and all. Thanks for your advice.